# What part of speech is missing in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

The instruction to an exercise in a grammar textbook tells us to complete the sentence

*Ils habitent dans cette maison de retraite : ce sont des .... .*

with "un participe présent ou un adjectif verbal du verbe *résider*". But don't we need a noun here?

Comment: On peut avoir les deux, adjectif et substantif ... https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9sidant

Comment: There is an error; it should be "un participe présent, un adjectif verbal, ou nom (substantif),  dérivé du verbe résider".

Comment: We do need a noun, there's a flaw in the instructions.

Comment: Those who say *résidants* is wrong / is not a noun could ponder on why *résidants de la maison de retraite* is so widespread. Also I find this explanation : [Résident ou résidant ?](https://www.aleos.asso.fr/resident-ou-residant.html) clear. As often it comes down to what point of view we want to convey.

Answer (score 4):

I think the expected solution is **résidents**.

Here "résident" is used as a common noun. It's important to note that you can also write "résidant" as explained [here](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/resident-et-residant-0), but that the Académie Française advises against this spelling.

With a present participle value, it would be used in this way instead:

*Ma cousine, **résidant** au 56 rue Diderot, va bientôt déménager.*

> My cousin, living at 56 rue Diderot, will soon be moving.

And as a qualifying adjective:

*C'est l'appartement où elle était **résidante***.

> This is the apartment where she used to live.

To come back to the question in the exercise, as you've already noticed, after the indefinite article **des** we mostly place a noun, but sometimes an adjective, as in the sentence *Ils sont des sympathiques **résidents***.

If you could add an image of the exercise in question, perhaps we could be sure that it's an error.

Comment: «  but sometimes an adjective » : ce n'est pas exact, le mot « résident » a atteint la qualité de véritable nom ; certains adjectifs, comme « heureux » ou « invincible » ont la nature d'*adjectif employé comme substantif*, et d'autres adjectifs ne peuvent avoir qu'un moindre caractère nominal  (usage elliptique en contexte restreint, pas dans les dictionnaires) (« les secs sont brulés les premiers, les verts sont mis à sécher (des rondins de bois, par exemple)).  Il y a donc une erreur dans  « un participe présent ou un adjectif verbal du verbe résider ».

Comment: @LPH The part of the answer you quote only states that the word that immediately follows the indefinite article _des_ is usually a noun, occasionally an adjective, which is completely correct – there is no doubt that _sympathiques_ in the example given is an adjective. The quote doesn’t deal with whether _résident_ is a noun or an adjective.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There is probably a confusion in your mind. "Sympathique" is an adjective, but that is not what "des" determines; "des" can only determine a noun, and that noun is "résidents". However the sentence should be "Ce sont de sympathiques voisins.", or, as usual, "Ce sont des résidents sympathiques." (The normal place of this adjective is after the noun.). Whether you add "sympathique" in the OP's text makes no difference: "résidents" has to be the noun, not the adjective (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9sident). "Un participe présent ou un adjectif verbal" is not enough.

Comment: @LPH No, no confusion. The part of the answer that you quoted doesn’t say anything about what the article _modifies_ but what _comes after_ the article – viz., the word immediately following it. That will most frequently be a noun, but it can sometimes be an adjective modifying a noun. I agree that the exercise is clearly looking for a noun, not a participle or adjective, and that the instructions are wrong; but that is completely irrelevant to the quote. I’m only saying that, “after the indefinite article _des_ we mostly place a noun, but sometimes an adjective” is not an incorrect statement.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The fact that the adjective comes between the head and the determiner (des)—which amounts to "right after the determiner— has nothing to do with the question. Then  user Hippo goes on with "perhaps we could be sure "; the fact is that we _are_ sure: "résident" is a noun and cannot be called an adjective. That is what I am saying.

Comment: I would like to thank everybody for the comments and to apologize for a delay with the image of the exercise. Unfortunately, I have failed to figure out how to add the image, therefore I am adding a link to the webpage which contains this exercise. It's  sentence i in Exercise 9 on https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/page/15570830.

Comment: @Val The *collège* textbook you link to is for French natives, not specially meant for FLE students. The point of the exercise you refer to is to test students on whether to agree the missing *ant* word. The expected answer in the teacher's book is *Ils habitent dans cette maison de retraite : ce sont des résidents.*  Although I consider *résidants* in this sentence to be perfectly correct (cf my previous comment), there's a problem with either the instruction in the exercise or with the given correct answer.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, None. The exercises were given to us by our teacher.